# Module translation - All store loses translation

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1, inline-translations

Hi Magento friends.

I've installed Magento 1.9 with a brazilian translation.. It's working.. All Magento default pages was translated perfectly.

After this, I've created a vendor/seller module in Magento frontend. The module it's working, but when trying to "internationalize" the module, something strange is happening..

Please, look the images attached. In homepage, everything it's ok (in Portuguese) and the inline translate it's appearing (i've enabled it in admin). But in my module page (/seller), the inline translate doesn't appears and the **WHOLE** page is in English, including the words that appears in Portuguese in others store pages.

Anybody could help me? I'm completely lost..

Parts of code here: http://forum.escolamagento.com/index.php?/topic/13692-traducao-em-modulo/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using magento developer mode?

**When the developer mode is on**:

### *"less"* translations

Block Object and Translations have to be in the same module

It will only be translated what is in the translate CSV of the Module
(`app/locale/de_DE/My_Module.csv`),

**Translation may need the Standard-Data-Helper** `MyCompany_MyModule_Helper_Data`

^ to make sure all translations are delivered through a module

[From a talk by Rico Neitzel and me](http://theslidesareonline.de)